Given a $X,Y$-bigraph and matchings $M,M'$, $M$ saturates $S\subseteq X$ & $M'$ saturates $T\subseteq Y$, is there a matching that saturates $T\cup S$
This question is taken from Douglas B. West's Introduction to Graph Theory, exercise 3.1.13.
Question: Let $M$ and $M'$ be matchings in an $X,Y$-bigraph $G$. Suppose that $M$ saturates $S\subseteq X$ and $M'$ saturates $T\subseteq Y$. Prove that $G$ has a matching that saturates $S \cup T$.
My approach:
Proof.
Let $G$ be a $X,Y$-bigraph with matchings $M$ and $M'$ s. t. $M$ saturates $S\subseteq X$ and $M'$ saturates $T\subseteq Y$. We construct a subgraph F with edges $M\cup M'$ and vertices $S\cup T$. The graph will have $\delta(F)=1$ since an edge from either $M$ or $M'$ will saturate a vertex, and $\Delta(F)=2$ since at most an edge from $M$ and an edge from $M'$ will saturate a vertex.
We remove edges from the vertex $v$, $v\in F$ and $\deg_F(v) = 2$, such that we only remove a single edge where the neighbouring vertex's degree is also 2, i.e. $u,\ u\in N_F(v);\ \deg_F(u)=2$. Now we are left with a matching that saturates every vertex from $F$ exactly once.
Is my approach sufficient for proving that now no vertex will have a degree of exactly one?

You are not far. What if a degree 2 vertex is adjacent to two degree 1 vertices?

Valid question, although I am a bit puzzled - can that even happen? Imagine the three vertices $v \in S$ and $u,d \in T$, for the matchings mentioned above, there will have to be at least 3 edges, since one will have to saturate $v$, one for $c$ and one for $d$, if deg$(v) = 2$, then one edge must be in $M'$ and the other in $M$ (since no two edges can have the same incident vertex), meaning at least one other edge will force either $c$ or $d$ to have a degree of $2$.
Is my reasoning correct?

You can have $v\in S$, $u\in T$ and $w\in Y\setminus T$, with $M={vw}$ and $M'={uv}$. The vertex $v$ is of degree 2 and surrounded by degree 1 vertices. Actually, I see in your question that $F$ is defined on vertices $S\cup T$, but edges of $M$ or $M'$ may span other vertices...

That is true, thanks for pointing it out, so maybe the graph $F$ is not supposed to be defined on the vertices $S \cup T$, rather as a subgraph on $G$, with the same edge set I mentioned, and try to prove it on that?

Yes, the graph will be a collection of cycles and paths, you just need to describe which edges you kept to cover $S$ and $T$.

I later managed to prove it (sry for the late response, had a lot on my schedule). I think the main hint was to take the subgraph on $G$ and then construct the matching such that we seek out $M,M'$alternating paths, such that one satisfies $S$ and the other will satisfy $T$ in all cases. And then pick out such edges so that all the vertices are saturated by the new matching.
